# undefined method `contact_forms_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, simple-form

I am running into an error with a form I am trying to create:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `contact_forms_path' for #<#<Class
```

The thing is I never created a `contact_forms` route, so I do not know why I am getting an undefined method for the `contact_forms_path`.

My route for the contact form is:

```
get "/contact_form/new", to: "contact_form#new"
```

My view for this form is `new.html.erb` within my contact_form directory

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact_form do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
    <%= f.input :last_name %>
    <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'example@email.com' %>
    <%= f.input :address %>
    <%= f.input :city %>
    <%= f.input :state %>
    <%= f.input :zip_code %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My model is `contact_form.rb` and my controller is `contact_form_controller.rb`.

I could use a little direction. Any help is appreciated. I can pass along more info if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

add this to your routes:

```
post "/contact_form", to: "contact_form#create"
```

open up the terminal and run:

```
rake routes|grep contact_form
```

You should get something like this as a response:

```
contact_form_new GET      /contact_form/new(.:format)         contact_form#new
contact_form POST        /contact_form(.:format)              contact_form#create
```

This gives you the path for the route. Now you can specify that path in the simple_form_for:

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact_form, url: contact_form_path, method: :post do |f| %>
```

Comment: This worked. I had everything except your last line. So when creating a form do you always need to illicitly state the url and the method?

Comment: Thanks for getting me through this :)

Answer (score 2):

`form_for` assumes a default url for new `Foo` records as `foos_path` as explained here...

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

You need to specify the path that the `contact_form` will post to...

```
post "/contact_forms", to: "contact_forms#create", as: 'contact_forms"
```

That will be the route that receives the params when you submit the form.

Note that as a shorthand you could just specify in your routes.rb

```
resources :contact_forms, only: [:new, :create]
```

(This assumes that you will use the more conventional `contact_forms#new` ... convention-over-configuration is to use plural for controller names)

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for the answer. I am still having trouble with the pluralization of contact_form(s). When I change my routes to resources :contact_forms, I get an uninitialized constant error, but when I leave it as resources :contact_form, my undefined method contact_forms_path error still persists.

Comment: You have an uninitialized constant error because your `ContactFormController` should be `ContactFormsController` *and* you have to change the file name as well... `contact_forms_controller.rb`

Comment: @bosskovic's answer works but it doesn't follow the rails convention